# WebSocket connection to ... failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200

Tags: javascript, websocket, glassfish-4.1

I am trying to create websocket connection between Chrome Browser and Glassfish 4.1.1 server. Unfortunately, I get HTTP 200 message instead of 101.

Chrome DevTool log:

```
"WebSocket connection to 'ws://DOMAIN_NAME:8080/serverendpointdemo/' failed: 
Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200"
```

Client side code:

```
var ws = new WebSocket ("ws://" + document.location.host + "/serverendpointdemo/");
```

Server side code:

```
package com.za.tutorial.websocket;

import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnError;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;

@ServerEndpoint("/home/USER_NAME/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/serverendpointdemo")
public class ServerEndpointDemo {
    @OnOpen
    public void handleOpen() {
        System.out.println("Client is now connected...");
    }

    @OnMessage
    public String handleMessage (String message) {
       return null;
    }

    @OnClose
    public void handleClose () {
    }

    @OnError
    public void handleError (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I won it this way:
Client side Javascript code:

    var ws = new WebSocket ("ws://DOMAIN_NAME:8080/serverendpointdemo/serverendpointdemo");

Helpful links, if elseone got it:

[link](http://blog.martinandersson.com/making-a-java-ee-7-websocket-serverendpoint-class-discoverable/)

[link](https://glassfish.java.net/docs/4.0/error-message-reference.pdf)

[link](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/websocket-1_0-fr-eval-spec/JavaWebSocketAPI_1.0_Final.pdf?AuthParam=1469574317_cf28b611d89626ae8c534e5f783409ca)

Comment: It is a feature of the Glassfish Server. In GlassFish, if your application is deployed with the contextroot mycontextroot in a Web container listening at port 8080 of localhost, the WebSocket will be accessible using ws://localhost:8080/mycontextroot/hello. Full text: [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jsr356-1937161.html)

Answer (score 0):

serverside:
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/ws")
public class WebSocketConfig {

```
private String message = "";
private String to = "";
private String from = "";
private static final Set<Session> sessions = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<Session>());

@OnOpen
public void onOpen(Session session, EndpointConfig econfig) throws IOException {        
    System.out.println("New Web Socket Connection created");
    session.getBasicRemote().sendText("onOpen new socket connection");             
}

@OnClose
public void onClose(Session session) {     
        sessions.remove(session);
}

@OnMessage
public void onMessage(String message, Session session) throws IOException {

}
```

client side:

while making a connection you should specify the contextpath
var ws = new WebSocket ("ws://" + document.location.host +"/"+your-contextPathName+"/serverendpointdemo/");

http:  ws://hostname:port/contextpath/serverendpoint
https: wss://hostname:port/contextpath/serverendpoint

ex:
ws://document.location.host+"/WebsocketDemo/ws";

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue